# Where do I put session information? In HttpServletRequest.setAttribute()?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a servlet class which handles login. At the end of my login procedure, I do this:

```
// jsp page
...
Helper.loginUser(request);

// Helper.java
public static void loginUser(HttpServletRequest request) {

    request.getSession().setAttribute("username", "john");
}
```

in order to remember who a user is between page loads. In another servlet (which handles an ajax call), I need to see if the session is active for the user. That looks like this:

```
// OtherServlet.java
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String username = (String)req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
}
```

but getting the attribute always returns null. Where should I be storing my session information so I can recover it between different servlets?

Thanks

Comment: What are the URLs of your servlets? Specifically, do the URLs have the same hostname?

Comment: it's the same domain, the urls are like [mysite.com/user/login] and [mysite.com/user/reports].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is bound to a specific domain and by default also the context path. If `OtherServlet` runs at a different domain and/or context, then it'll get a completely different session.

If you'd like to share the session among different webapplication contexts on the same domain, then you need to configure the servletcontainer accordingly to set the cookie path to *empty*. In case of for example Tomcat you can do that by setting the `emptySessionPath` attribute of the [HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) to `true` in the `/conf/server.xml` file.

---

**Update**, after a recheck of your question, the `Helper.loginUser(request)` approach in the JSP is not a good practice. You should be doing this in a Servlet class. By the way, that may after all also be the cause that the servletcontainer fails to set the session cookie because the response headers are already sent, but you should already have noticed a self-explaining `IllegalStateException` in the server logs then.

To help you a bit further, here's a basic kickoff example of the correct way to login an user:

HTML form in JSP:

```
<form action="login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`doPost()` method of a Servlet which is mapped on `url-pattern` of `/login`:

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); // Login user.
    response.sendRedirect("home"); // Redirect to home/succes page.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown username/password, try again"); // Set error message.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Redisplay login.jsp.
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't follow the different contexts part - the urls are the same domain, like [mysite.com/user/login] and [mysite.com/user/reports].. how can I tell if the contexts are different?

Comment: You initially told that you've 2 servlets, but after checking the code closely it turns out that you're (ab)using a JSP to put the logged in user in session. This will not always work. Check the server logs. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that was a great example. I rewrote everything as suggested and it works now.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions please watch out what you're telling and posting. In this and the subsequent question the posted code contradicts with what you're telling. Use the *actual* code and use the correct terminology to avoid red herrings :)